# Reset Java field unresolved compilation problem

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jlabel

I'm trying to count the number of tries a user makes to guess a number in a java GUI program using swing.

I've created these variables to keep track of the number of tries:

```
    JLabel lblNumberOfTries = new JLabel("Number of tries:");
    lblNumberOfTries.setBounds(136, 219, 90, 13);
    getContentPane().add(lblNumberOfTries);
    
    txtNumberOfTries = new JTextField();
    txtNumberOfTries.setBounds(223, 219, 42, 13);
    getContentPane().add(txtNumberOfTries);
    txtNumberOfTries.setColumns(10);
```

And I need to reset them when the game restarts. For some reason I can reset the java field but not the label:

```
txtNumberOfTries.setText(""); // this is ok
lblNumberOfTries.setText(""); // this gives an error
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    lblNumberOfTries cannot be resolved

    at GuessingGame.newGame(GuessingGame.java:50)
    at GuessingGame.main(GuessingGame.java:110)
```

This is the class and functions where the labels and fields are in my program:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;      
    
    public class GuessingGame extends JFrame {
        public GuessingGame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Tim's Hi-Lo Guessing Game");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Tim's Hi-Lo Guessing Game");
        lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTitle.setBounds(0, 10, 436, 32);
        getContentPane().add(lblTitle);

        JLabel lblGuessANumber = new JLabel("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
        lblGuessANumber.setBackground(new Color(240, 240, 240));
        lblGuessANumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblGuessANumber.setBounds(147, 54, 215, 13);
        getContentPane().add(lblGuessANumber);

        txtGuess = new JTextField();
        txtGuess.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            checkGuess();
        });
        txtGuess.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        txtGuess.setBounds(260, 122, 27, 19);
        getContentPane().add(txtGuess);
        txtGuess.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGuess = new JButton("Guess!");
        btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                checkGuess();
            }
        });
        btnGuess.setBounds(172, 121, 85, 21);
        getContentPane().add(btnGuess);

        lblOutput = new JLabel("Enter a number above and click Guess!");
        lblOutput.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblOutput.setBounds(58, 196, 350, 13);
        getContentPane().add(lblOutput);
        
        JLabel lblNumberOfTries = new JLabel("Number of tries:");
        lblNumberOfTries.setBounds(136, 219, 90, 13);
        getContentPane().add(lblNumberOfTries);
        
        txtNumberOfTries = new JTextField();
        txtNumberOfTries.setBounds(223, 219, 42, 13);
        getContentPane().add(txtNumberOfTries);
        txtNumberOfTries.setColumns(10);
}

public void newGame() {
    theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    txtNumberOfTries.setText("");
    lblNumberOfTries.setText("");
    
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that `lblNumberOfTries` is declared as a local variable in a method and you are trying to access it from a different method. You should make it a member of the class so that it can be accessed from different methods of the class. Consider posting a [mcve] so that I don't have to guess what your problem is.

Comment: OK I've included the two functions where the labels  and fields are in my program in the updated OP. Let me know if I need to provide any more info.

Comment: Was exactly this @Abra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after seeing the full file, there are 2 main points:

You need to define a field `private JLabel lblNumberOfTries;` in the class

You also need to remove 'JLabel' from around line 98 in the GuessingGame constructor (the method defined `public GuessingGame()` is known as the constuctor) so that it becommes `lblNumberOfTries = new JLabel("Number of tries:");`. This will stop you from redeclaring the variable.

At some point, you're also going to want to add a private int field called `numberOfTries`

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it. Now I need to figure out a way to get the numberOfTries to display in the GUI. I'm real new at this. But thanks for your help so far!

Comment: No worries! That part shouldn't be too hard so I'm sure you'll be fine!

Comment: Cool thanks again! I'll try to work on this later. Good stuff! I'm glad it's starting to work. There's also a thread I have on this on the java ranch if you want to follow along: 

https://coderanch.com/t/737583/java/Java-swing-GUI-program-add#3429683